# Create service server in rqt c++

Tags: ros, roscpp, service, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I need to create a service in c++ using qt.
I found an example to do this in python, but not in c++.

What I need to consider to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195909/create-service-server-in-rqt-c++/) by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2014-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-10-25**:
How is the question specific to rqt? Does the standard C++ tutorial not work (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some differences, not mentioned in http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29). The service must be a class member of your plugin class; however, services/publishers/subscribers as class members are not so special to rqt; it's a quite common practise...

A few notes, special to rqt:

- advertise your service in initPlugin
- use `getNodeHandle()` as NodeHandle if your service can run in a single thread (with your GUI); note that long running services may block your GUI
- use `getNodeHandleMT()` as NodeHandle if your service may run asynchronously with your GUI. Thread-safety? Your Job!!!
- call service.shutDown() in shutDownPlugin(). Otherwise your service can be called after your GUI Plugin was unloaded which might cause seg fault.

Your code may look like:

Header:

```
#include "beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h"    

  // this should be know to you
class YourRqtPlugin

  : public rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin
{

  Q_OBJECT

public:
  // this should be know to you
  YourRqtPlugin();

  virtual void initPlugin(qt_gui_cpp::PluginContext& context);

  virtual void shutdownPlugin();
    
protected:

      // this is new for the service
     bool add(beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Request  &req,
                    beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Response &res);
      // and this is new for the service
    ros::ServiceServer service;

};
```

Source:

```
YourRqtPlugin::YourRqtPlugin()  : 
  rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin()
{
  setObjectName("Qt based service server"); // or whatever
}

void YourRqtPlugin::initPlugin(qt_gui_cpp::PluginContext& context)
{  
     <<.........................>>
         other GUI intialization stuff
     <<.........................>>
      // advertise your service in initPlugin
      // use getNodeHandle() to get a nodehandle reference
     service = getNodeHandle().advertiseService("add_two_ints", &YourRqtPlugin::add, this);
}
  
void YourRqtPlugin::shutdownPlugin()
{
    // shutdown service; otherwise seg faults possible if service is called after plugin was unloaded
    service.shutDown();
}

bool YourRqtPlugin::add(beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Request  &req,
                    beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Response &res)
{

     res.sum = req.a + req.b;
     ROS_INFO("request: x=%ld, y=%ld", (long int)req.a, (long int)req.b);
     ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%ld]", (long int)res.sum);
     return true;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-10-29**:
I tried to add a Service to the Cartesian path planner Plugin. But I couldn't. The plugin didn't start.
After many hours, I realized that I should define the service (service = getNodeHandle().advertiseService("add_two_ints", &YourRqtPlugin::add, this)) at the final of the init function.

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-10-29**:
That was maybe because the plugin need more time to start. So, I used a sleep(10) before define the service and now all works fine.